# DB2 - Get all records based on date

Tags: sql, db2

I have a date column called "START" in my table. I want to fetch all records from that table if the difference between current date and start date is more than 2 weeks. Can you please help?

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `days` function returns an integer representation of a date, in days, so you can just do simple subtraction:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE days(current date) - days(START) > 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform date math using *labeled durations* without having to use the `DAYS` function:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE START < CURRENT DATE - 14 DAYS
```

More info on labeled durations is available in the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023457.html).